# Html.TextBoxFor not rendering when added by a library

Tags: javascript, html, html-helper

I'm currently working on a website at work. Everything's been working so far, except when I've moved a function to a library so it can be reusable.

The function is a click event for a set of two radio buttons. When the "Yes" button is clicked, a textbox and it's label need to appear. When the "No" button is clicked, they need to disappear.

The label is appearing just fine on the "Yes" click. And the function as a whole worked perfectly on the page itself. However, when I moved the script to a library for reusability within the project, the textbox no longer appears. I have tried swapping out for an input tag, with similar results.

The relevant html:

```
@ModelType PROJECT.Form

@Code
    ViewData("Title") = "PageTitle"
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutPage.Desktop.vbhtml"
End Code
<script>
    $(function () { initFunction() })
</script>

@Using Html.BeginForm("Process", "Home")
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.Hidden("page", 4)
    @<div id="formColumn" class="grid_19 alpha">
        <h3>Process Title</h3>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Page Title</legend>
            <ol class="grid_18 push_1">
                //a couple yes/no questions here, works fine
                <li><label>Question 3</label></li>
                <li>
                    <ol id="appendHere"class="horizontalList clearfix">
                        <li><label>Yes</label></li>
                        <li>@Html.RadioButtonFor(Function(a) a.Q3Radio, True)</li>
                        <li><label>No</label></li>
                        <li>@Html.RadioButtonFor(Function(a) a.Q3Radio, False)</li>
                    </ol>
                </li>
                //more working stuff
            </ol>
            <div class="clear"></div> 
            <button name="submit" id="submit" value="submit" class="push_1">Submit</button>
            <button name="cancel" id="cancel" value="cancel" class="push_1">Cancel</button>
            <button name="back" id="back" value="back" class="push_1">Back</button>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
End Using
```

The javascript:

```
function initFunction() {
    $(function () { $("input[name=Q3Radio]").click(function () { handleQ3Check(this) }) })

    var check = true
    function handleQ3Check(elem) {
        if (elem.value == "True") {
                if (check) {
                    $('#appendHere').append('<li class="appended"><label>Amount: $</label></li><li class="appended">@Html.TextBoxFor(Function(a) a.appendAmount)</li>')
                    $(function () { $("input[name=appendAmount]").blur(function () { handleFees(this, 'stuff') }) })
                    check = false
                }
            } else {
            var appendedInput = $('.appended')
            if (appendedInput != null) {
                handleFees(appendedInput, 'stuff')
                $(appendedInput).remove()
                check = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As stated above, I have tried making the textbox out of an input tag, but that does not appear. What appears with this case is `Amount: $ @Html.TextboxFor(Function(a) a.appendAmount)` exactly like that.

Any help or nudges in the right direction while I further attempt to debug the issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you're getting Razor and Javascript mixed up. The Razor @Html.TextBoxFor would be 'translated' on the server not on the client, where the Javascript is inserting it.

Comment: Wait, nevermind, I get what you said. The problem, though, is that the `<input>` tag wouldn't work either. It just plain doesn't show up, and this just shows the text. Do you know any way to get the textbox to show up, or what the bug may be?

Comment: The <label> tag appears so the <input> tag should. If you use Chrome press F12 and open up dev tools see what is in the Console. That might show errors with the javascript. Also try removing stuff and slowly adding it. If it works on the page then view source and see what the actual HTML being rendered is.

Comment: So you're saying that this 
`$('#appendHere').append('<li class="appended"><label>Amount: $</label></li><li class="appended"><input type="text" name="amount" /></li>')` does NOT work?

Comment: @roryok No, it's not working. I'm trying it again to see what I can get. I'm using IE11, and their dev tools, and not getting any javascript error. With the `<input>` tag, it's actually not even showing the tag in the html. Just an empty `<li>` tag set.

Comment: I just ran the `<input>` tag method again, but this time without the type, as I've seen it on another page on this project that was written by one of my coworkers. Without the `type="text"` part, and just the name and id that I want on the box, it worked perfectly. I think I can chalk this one up to a bug, since just deleting that part fixed it.

Comment: The type might be important, <input> tags can be of type submit or hidden. But I think you are correct it might just be a typo. See what happens when you add the type back in.

Comment: It must've been a typo, because copying and pasting the syntax from the comment by @roryok worked this time. Thank you both for your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you include the Javascript in the same vbhtml file the reason why it works is that the vbhtml file gets compiled before it is then sent out to the client's browser. Have a look at the javascript that is getting rendered either by viewing the source or using developer tools/or similar in your favourite browser.

When you ask javascript to write out

```
$('#appendHere').append('<li class="appended"><label>Amount: $</label></li>
<li class="appended">@Html.TextBoxFor(Function(a) a.appendAmount)</li>')
```

It will do just that.

Judging by your comments it seems as though you're already aware of this though :-) and that you're making progress.

Comment: You learn something new every day. Though to be fair... the coworker that started this project didn't seem to know that either, because when I asked him, he had no clue as to why it wasn't working. Thank you for your quick assistance in this matter.

Comment: Not a problem, a well-phrased question always gets answered quickly. Just luck though that I was passing by and had made similar mistakes last week!